# Sorting icon not replace jquery ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working on "sort tables" in ajax jquery with php,My sorting
function working properly but need to hide/show "sorting images", Right now one sided (desc)
sorting is working because unable to replace/change sorting image and status,
I just want whenever i click on "upper" icon then its status(asc) should pass and "down" image should display and if i click on "down" icon then status should pass and "up" icon should display,

Here is my code

```
<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;' id='postsList'>
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S.no</th>
        <th class="column_sort" id="name" data-order="desc" href="#">Title
        <img id="ASC" datas-order="desc" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/UpArrow.png">
        <img id="DESC" datas-order="asc" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/DownArrow.png" style="display:none;">
        </th>
        
        <th class="column_sort" id="symbol" data-order="desc" href="#">Symbol
        <img id="ASC" datas-order="desc" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/UpArrow.png">
        <img id="DESC" datas-order="asc" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assets/img/DownArrow.png" style="display:none;">
        </th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
```

Here is my php script code,Where i am wrong ?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){  
     $(document).on('click', '.column_sort', function(){  
        var column_name = $(this).attr("id");  
           var order = $(this).data("order");  
           var arrow = '';  
           var PageNumber= $("#pagination").find("strong").html();
         if(order == 'desc')  
           {  
                arrow = '&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>';  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                arrow = '&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>';  
           } 
           
          $.ajax({  
                 url:'<?=base_url()?>/Main/fetch_details/', 
                method:"POST",  
                data:{column_name:column_name, order:order ,PageNumber:PageNumber},  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                    $("#postsList tr:not(:first)").remove();
                     $("#postsList2").show();
                     $("#postsList2").html(data);
                      $('#'+column_name+'').replace('<img src="<?=base_url()?>/assets/img/DownArrow.png"/>');
                    return false;
                }  
           }) 
});  
 });  
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have the same id for multiple elements like `id="ASC"`, use class for this.

Comment: Also when you ask jQuery questions like this, then please post plain HTML and no PHP code. It is NOT a php question

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: Can you please write code then i can implement in my side

Comment: @amitfiles try replace `$('#'+column_name+'').replace` with `$('#'+column_name+'').html`. `.replace()` takes 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

Toggle:

```
$("#postsList .column_sort").on("click", "img" ,function(e) {
  $(this).sibling().toggle()
  $(this).toggle()
})
```

or have just one image

```
$("#postsList").on("click","[data-order]",function(e) {
  this.src = this.dataset.order === "desc" ? "/assets/img/UpArrow.png" : "/assets/img/DownArrow.png"
})
```